# Array splitting ending / beginning

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking to split an array into two, one containing the beginning and one containing the ending. If their is an odd number of array items I want the first to contain the extra one.

```
$array = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7');    
$beg = array('1','2','3','4');
$end = array('5','6','7');
```

Comment: array_slice & count should see you through. Have you tried looking at the "array functions" page of the manual? http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7');   
$count=count($array);
$num=$count/2;
if($count % 2 != 0)
{  
  $num++;
}    
print_r($array1=array_slice($array,0,$num));
print_r($array2=array_slice($array,$num));
```

Answer (score 1):

[`array_chunk`](http://php.net/array_chunk) anybody?

```
list($beginning, $ending) = array_chunk($array, ceil(count($array)/2));
```

[working codepad example](http://codepad.org/CRgKPMYw)

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can try array slice
You will find [examples here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)